# Is it possible to store a payload for all the user_id in mysql table with php by using looping method?

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a form in front-end where we can fill in the following details; Title, message and date. Upon clicking the submit button, the payload will be saved in Table 1 of the DB with user_id column NULL because no user_id is selected. There is too many user_id so is it possible to fetch all user_id from another table (Table 'user') and store the payload for each user_id? The purpose of storing the payload for all user_id is to enable the back-end dev to send notification to all the user_id. The payload will be the same for all user_id.

the following is my code in model (mvc) to store the data.

```
 `function set_news($form_data)
     {
        $data = array(
            'title' => $form_data['title'],
            'message' => $form_data['message'],
            'date' => $form_data['date'],
            
        );
        $this->db->select('user_id')->from('user')->where('user_status', 1);
        $query =  $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $val) {
            $value[$val['user_id']] = $val['user_id'];
        }
        
        $this->db->insert('news', $data);
     }`
```

I'm stuck at how to assign each user_id to the array(payload). Without the foreach part, the payload will be saved with user_id column Null, so I've added the foreach part but I'm not sure how to get on with that, as i'm still new to php. Kindly help if possible. Thank you.

This is the additional code I've added.

```
`$this->db->select('user_id')->from('user')->where('user_status', 1);
        $query =  $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $val) {
            $value[$val['user_id']] = $val['user_id'];
        }`
```

I'm expecting the data to be saved as below:

| title | message | date | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Greeting | Hello | 12/06/23 | 1001 |
| Greeting | Hello | 12/06/23 | 1002 |
| Greeting | Hello | 12/06/23 | 1003 |
| Greeting | Hello | 12/06/23 | 1004 |
| Greeting | Hello | 12/06/23 | 1005 |
| Greeting | Hello | 12/06/23 | 1006 |

But for now, when i submit, the user_id column is NULL.

Comment: Sounds like you just want an `UPDATE` statement, not an `INSERT`.

Comment: UPDATE would mean to add into the existing once. But i want it to store immediately as i submit. Meaning fetch all user_id and bind the payload to each user_id and then INSERT.

Comment: Yeah ok then don't do that. _Not_ storing identical data in multiple rows is kind of "DB Normalization 101". At the least you should store the message in another table and generate entries in a linking table for each user ID, but honestly your approach sounds inside-out and should probably be reconsidered.

Comment: All that said, you can't "insert a row for each user id" without a loop in PHP that performs an insert for every single user id.

Answer (score 0):

This method works perfectly. Loop through each array and store the data.

```
$user_id = array(1001, 1002, 1003...); 
foreach($user_id as $val){    
$data = array('title' => $form_data['title'],             
              'message' => $form_data['message'],             
               'date' => $form_data['date'],              
               'user_id' => $val          );   
$this->db->insert('info', $data); }
```